# How can I put a muzzle on the ErrorProvider component?

Tags: c#, winforms, errorprovider

I'm trying to use an ErrorProvider component.

I have a Close button on the form, and of course it also has the "X" close thingy in the NE corner of the form.

Once an error has been "raised" though, clicking the Close button or the Close box (or whatever that doohicky is called) are unresponsive/nonfunctional.

What must I do to allow the user to dismiss the form when it has errors on it?

Update:

Here's the code I'm trying now in the "Close" button's OnClick() handler - it still refuses to close:

```
private void buttonCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  formValidation.SetError(this, String.Empty);
  Close();
}
```

Updated again: Just for grimaces, I tried changing the "DialogResult" property from Canceled to None on the "Close" button, but that did not help (didn't expect it to - grasping at straws)

Neither did changing the button's "Causes Validation" property from True to False...

Updated yet again:

Here's all the pertinent that may or may not be fit to post:

```
        . . .
              const int MINIMUM_PASSWORD_LENGTH = 5;

        private string originalPassword {
            get { return textCurrentPassword.Text; }
        }

        private string newCandidatePassword1 {
            get { return textNewPassword.Text; }
        }

        private string newCandidatePassword2 {
            get { return textNewPasswordRepeated.Text; }
        }

        public ChangePassword() {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void textCurrentPassword_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e) {
            string error = null;

            if (originalPassword.Equals(String.Empty)) {
                error = currentPasswordInvalid;
                e.Cancel = true;
                //textCurrentPassword.Focus(); probably unnecessary because of .SetError() below
            };

            // TODO: Replace 1==2 with call that compares password with the current user's confirmed password
            if (1 == 2) {
                error = currentPasswordDoesNotMatchCurrentUser;
                e.Cancel = true;
            }

            formValidation.SetError((Control)sender, error);
            if (null != error) {
                ;
            }
        }

        private void textNewPassword_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e) {
            string error = null;

            if (newCandidatePassword1.Length < 5) {
                error = newPasswordInvalid;
                e.Cancel = true;
            }

            formValidation.SetError((Control)sender, error);
            if (null != error) {
                ;
            }
        }

        private void textNewPasswordRepeated_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e) {
            string error = null;

            // Long enough?
            if (newCandidatePassword2.Length < MINIMUM_PASSWORD_LENGTH) {
                error = newPasswordInvalid;
                e.Cancel = true;
            }

            // New passwords match?
            if (!newCandidatePassword2.Equals(newCandidatePassword1)) {
                error = newPasswordsDoNotMatch;
                e.Cancel = true;
            }

            // They match, but all three match (undesirable)
            if (!originalPassword.Equals(newCandidatePassword1)) {
                error = newPasswordSameAsOld;
                e.Cancel = true;
            }

            // Unique across the user base?
            // TODO: Replace 1==2 with call that verifies this password is unique 
            if (1 == 2) {
                error = newPasswordNotUnique;
                e.Cancel = true;
            }

            formValidation.SetError((Control)sender, error);
            if (null != error) {
                ;
            }
        }

        private void buttonCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            foreach (Control ctrl in this.Controls) { 
                formValidation.SetError(ctrl, string.Empty); 
            } 
            Close(); 
        }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Errorprovider shows error on using windows close button(X)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2481706/errorprovider-shows-error-on-using-windows-close-buttonx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can trying clearing SetError in your Close button handler:

```
private void buttonCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (Control ctrl in this.Controls)
    {
        formValidation.SetError(ctrl, string.Empty);
    }
    Close();
}
```

Also double check that your buttonCancel is indeed hooked up to this handler. Put a breakpoint and make sure that you are at least getting into this function.

Comment: That gives me, "Cannot assign to 'SetError' because it is a 'method group'"

Comment: @Clay, can you show me the code in your button click hander. I also corrected my code as I posted it from memory.

Comment: Posted above. "This is this!" (movie quote to reach the minimum character requirement).

Comment: @ClayShannon, updated code, although I'm not convinced that the errorProvided is preventing your programing from closing. Can you close it when there are no errors on the from?

Comment: no, it's not getting there. But I think it's because my response is to set focus to the TextBox with the error. I'll comment that out and see what happens...

Comment: no, I can't, because it sees one of the TextBoxes is empty and goes to there... apparently my ErrorProvider philosophy is wrong.

Comment: I see I'd already commented out the calls to .Focus(). So, I'm cutting to the chase and posting all relevant code above. Either I'm doing somethng fundamentally backwards here, or something very odd is happening (or both).

Comment: @ClayShannon, `e.Cancel = true;` is your culprit. It's stopping the validating event and preventing you from moving off the control until the user fixes the error.

Comment: Removing e.Cancel = true does allow the form to close; however, you have to click the "Close" button twice for either one - once to 86 the blinking error icon, and then once again to actually close it.